# How to enable MPRIS control of a GTK application in KDE Plasma?

Tags: sound, kde, gtk, function-keys, mpris

I came across a GTK application ([Blanket](https://github.com/rafaelmardojai/blanket/)), which can be controlled with a laptop's play/pause button in GTK based DEs like GNOME, XFCE and Cinnamon (tested in Ubuntu 20.04, Xubuntu 20.04, and Linux Mint Cinnamon), but the laptop's function keys cannot play/pause the app in KDE Plasma (Kubuntu 20.04).

Also, the app does not register itself under applications playing sound, in the audio control applet of KDE Plasma (while other software like VLC do so).
Is there any way to use the MPRIS controls of a GTK app in KDE Plasma, so that it can be conveniently used in Kubuntu?

Nowadays KDE has excellent compatibility with GTK, so this may be achievable.